# MySql npm issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Node js Query

```
var email = "devsassyinfotech@gmail.com";
var query = 'SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE email = '+eval(email);
```

MySql Query

```
SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE email = "devsassyinfotech@gmail.com"
```

I used MySQL npm for the database connection.I want to use My SQL query using node js.
so I want to add var query attach to email as a string like MySql query.

```
var query = 'SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE email = "devsassyinfotech@gmail.com" ';
```

Comment: So, whats your question. This feels like half a thought.... To actually get answers, please be specific with what you want as an end result, what you have tried and what errors you have got.

Comment: i want query variable print like this  'SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = "devsassyinfotech@gmail.com" '

Comment: Why do you use `eval()` in the first place ?

Comment: When you use the code as supplied, what is the output